# Adjoint of U_p and Atkin-Lehner theory

Tags: modular-forms, hecke-operators

In the below everything is quoted from Miyake's "Modular Forms".

Let $p \mid N$. We have Hecke operator
$T(p)\in \mathscr{R}(N)$ (pg. 135) on $S_{k}(\Gamma_0(N))$ given by
$$T(p) = \Gamma_0(N)\big(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & p \end{smallmatrix}\big)\Gamma_0(N).$$
Since $\Gamma_0(N) \big(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & p \end{smallmatrix}\big) \Gamma_0(N) = 
\bigsqcup_{m=0}^{p-1} \big(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & m \\ 0 & p \end{smallmatrix}\big) \Gamma_0(N) = 
\bigsqcup_{m=0}^{p-1} \Gamma_0(N) \big(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & m \\ 0 & p \end{smallmatrix}\big)$, for 
$f \in S_{k}(\Gamma_0(N))$ we have,
$T(p)(f)=p^{k/2-1} \sum_{m=0}^{p-1} f|_{k} \big(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & m \\ 0 & p \end{smallmatrix}\big)$. This $T(p)$ is same as $U$ operator $U_p$.

Further, we have operator $T^*(p) \in \mathscr{R}^*(N)$ on $S_{k}(\Gamma_0(N))$ given by
$T^*(p) = \Gamma_0(N) \big(\begin{smallmatrix} p & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix}\big) \Gamma_0(N)$ and
and as (by eq. (4.5.19) and line 1 of pg. 137) 
$\Gamma_0(N) \big(\begin{smallmatrix} p & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix}\big) \Gamma_0(N) = 
\bigsqcup_{m=0}^{p-1} \big(\begin{smallmatrix} p & -m \\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix}\big) \Gamma_0(N) = 
\bigsqcup_{m=0}^{p-1} \Gamma_0(N) \big(\begin{smallmatrix} p & -m \\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix}\big)$, so
$$T^*(p)(f) = p^{k/2-1} \sum_{m=0}^{p-1} f|_{k} \big(\begin{smallmatrix} p & -m \\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix}\big) = 
p^{k-1} \sum_{m=0}^{p-1} f(pz-m) = p^{k-1} \sum_{m=0}^{p-1} f(pz) = p^{k}f(pz).$$
By Theorem 4.5.4 of Miyake (or Theorem 2.8.2)
for $f,\ g \in S_{2k}(\Gamma_0(N))$ we have 
$\langle T(p)(f),\ g \rangle = \langle f,\ T^*(p)(g) \rangle = 
\langle f,\ p^{k}V_p(g) \rangle$ where $V_p(g)(z)=g(pz)$.

The problem is that on the one hand $T^*(p)$ preserves level, 
on the other hand $V_p$ increases level. In fact following 
pg. 165, line -12, if we start with $f = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nq^n$ 
a primitive new form of level $N$ then $T(p) f = a_p f$ and since $f$ is also an eigenfunction under $T^*(p)$ we have $T^*(p) f = \overline{a_p} f$. But this implies $p^{k}V_p(f) = \overline{a_p} f$ which is a contradiction as 
$V_p(f)$ cannot be of the level $N$ by Atkin-Lehner.

I am unable to find mistake, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not true that $\Gamma_0(N)(p 0;0 1)\Gamma_0(N)$ is the disjoint union of $\Gamma_0(N)(p,-m;0,1)$ and your justification seems to involve commuting a matrix and a group which don't commute. Your claim about what $T^*(p)$ is is incorrect; it does preserve the level.

Comment: PS one sanity test I usually use for these decompositions of double cosets is "$\Gamma_0(N)$ contains $(1,1;0,1)$ and what does this tell us?". You write that a double coset is a disjoint union of $\Gamma_0(N)(p,-m;0,1)$ and multiplying this latter matrix by $(1,1;0,1)$ on the left gives us $(p,1-m;0,1)$ which instantly tells us that your single cosets aren't disjoint.

Comment: Thank you very much. I realised my mistake, also $\Gamma_0(N)(1,0;0,p)\Gamma_0(N)$ is not a disjoint union of $(1,m;0,p)\Gamma_0(N)$. In fact $\Gamma_0(N)(p,0;0,1)\Gamma_0(N)$ is disjoint union of
$\Gamma_0(N)(p,0;Nm,1)$. Miyake's $T^*(p)$ is an adjoint of $T(p)$ wrt Petersson product on $S_{k}(N)$ and it commutes with $T(n)$ for $(n,N)=1$.
Also using $\langle f|_k(a,b;c,d),\ g\rangle = \langle f,\ g|_k(d,-b;-c,a)\rangle$ we have $\langle T(p)(f),\ g \rangle = \langle f,\ p^{k}V_p(g) \rangle$ . But
this $p^{k}V_p$ is not equal to $T^*(p)$. So we are fine.  Thank you again.